# Creating a new column in dataframe with range of values

Tags: python, pandas

I need to divide range of my passengers age onto 5 parts and create a new column where will be values from 0 to 4 respectively for every part(For 1 range value 0 for 2 range value 1 etc)

```
a = range(0,17)
b = range(17,34)
c = range(34, 51)
d = range(51, 68)
e = range(68,81)
a1 = titset.query('Age >= 0 & Age < 17')
a2 = titset.query('Age >= 17 & Age < 34')
a3 = titset.query('Age >= 34 & Age < 51')
a4 = titset.query('Age >= 51 & Age < 68')
a5 = titset.query('Age >= 68 & Age < 81')
titset['Age_bin'] = a1.apply(0 for a in  range(a))
```

Here what i tried to do but it does not work. I also pin dataset picture

[DATASET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iknvo.png)

I expect to get result where i'll see a new column named 'Age_bin' and values 0 in it for Age from 0 to 16 inclusively, values 1 for age from 17 to 33 and other 3 rangers

Answer (score 1):

Binning with pandas [cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) is appropriate here, try:

```py
titset['Age_bin'] = titset['Age'].cut(bins=[0,17,34,51,68,81], include_lowest=True, labels=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the variable `a` is a range object, which you are calling `range(a)` again, which is equivalent to `range(range(0, 17))`, hence the error.

Secondly, even if you fixed the above problem, you will run into an error again since `.apply` takes in a callable (i.e., a function be it defined with `def` or a lambda function).

If your goal is to assign a new column that represents the age group that each row is in, you can just filter with your result and assign them:

```
titset = pd.DataFrame({'Age': range(1, 81)})


a = range(0,17)
b = range(17,34)
c = range(34, 51)
d = range(51, 68)
e = range(68,81)

a1 = titset.query('Age >= 0 & Age < 17')
a2 = titset.query('Age >= 17 & Age < 34')
a3 = titset.query('Age >= 34 & Age < 51')
a4 = titset.query('Age >= 51 & Age < 68')
a5 = titset.query('Age >= 68 & Age < 81')

titset.loc[a1.index, 'Age_bin'] = 0
titset.loc[a2.index, 'Age_bin'] = 1
titset.loc[a3.index, 'Age_bin'] = 2
titset.loc[a4.index, 'Age_bin'] = 3
titset.loc[a5.index, 'Age_bin'] = 4
```

Or better yet, use a for loop:

```
age_groups = [0, 17, 34, 51, 68, 81]

for i in range(len(age_groups) - 1):
    subset = titset.query(f'Age >= {age_groups[i]} & Age < {age_groups[i+1]}')
    titset.loc[subset.index, 'Age_bin'] = i
```